# Finite State Machine of concurrent system

Tags: fsm

I devise a new algorithm to use flow analysis technique to detect unreachability faults in concurrent systems. I need to find some finite state machine of large concurrent system (probably with hundreds of states) such as network protocols to do experiments. However, I can't find it on the web. Can anyone give me some clue?

I need state machines that the transitions between them should be synchronized.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TCP states:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg

this is not big but good one.

Answer (score 0):

Any non-trivial Erlang program. Erlang programs usually consist of hundreds of (potentially concurrent) processes exchanging messages.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not familiar with Erlang. Can you give me some examples and how to convert the program to FSM.

Comment: I guess a good example you might see described in the Erlang: the movie video: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-5830318882717959520# and in their historical paper: http://www.labouseur.com/courses/erlang/history-of-erlang-armstrong.pdf. This is a difficult matter, though--the Erlang FSM are usually very complex, and they need good deal of understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the [SIP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) state machine when used with [Reliable Provisional Responses](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3262.txt) and [ICE](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc5245.html) gets really large. But reconstructing a state diagram from those standards will be time consuming (SIP developers all over the world would be grateful for having such a diagram, if it was correct and complete).

[Q.931](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Q.931-199805-I/en) (the ISDN UNI protocol) has nice SDL state diagrams. It's only 25 states though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I looked at Q.931's SDL state diagrams, but I don't know the relationship of SDL diagram and FSM. Also, there are quite a lot number of diagrams (in the pdf), I am a little bit confused how they are synchronized since no transition names are provided. Can you give me some hint?

Thanks again.

Comment: Figure A.1 in Q.931 give a short overview of the notation. The rounded rectangle at the top of a graph represent the state before some event, the 'flag' symbols represent events (called 'primitive' in ITU speak), and the rounded rectangles at the bottom represent the state after a certain event happened.